# How much is this amount?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following sentence is from The Invisible Man by H.G.Wells. Please explain the italicized part:

They heard the chink of money, and realised that the robber had found the housekeeping reserve of gold— *two pounds ten in half sovereigns altogether*.

Comment: The Invisible Man was published in 1897. The [inflation adjuster here](http://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/bills/article-1633409/Historic-inflation-calculator-value-money-changed-1900.html) only allows 1901 as the earliest date but says that £2.10s would be worth £268.30 in today's money.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the inflation of money.

Comment: It is about understanding the novella The Invisible Man by H.G.Wells.

Comment: Mr Google has the answer -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereign_(British_coin) Voting to close... it is not hard to find out what a sovereign is.

Answer (score 3):

In the days before decimalisation (15 February 1971), an expression such as "Two pounds ten" meant "Two pounds and ten shillings".

There were twenty shillings to the pound, so ten shillings was half a pound.

A *sovereign* was a coin worth one pound; a *half-sovereign* was another coin, worth ten shillings.

So this means "Two pounds and ten shillings in half-sovereign coins".

Comment: Would that be five coins (in half sovereigns) total, then? And were half sovereigns made of gold, the quote includes "reserve of gold".

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Yes [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_sovereign). "Modern half sovereigns, from 1817 onwards, have a diameter of 19.30 mm, a thickness of ~0.99 mm, a weight of 3.99 g, are made of 22 carat (916⅔ %) crown gold alloy, and contain 0.1176 troy ounces (3.6575 g) of gold. The reverse side, featuring St. George slaying a dragon was designed by Benedetto Pistrucci, whose initials appear to the right of the date."